# Magento2 attributes construct error in Entity

Tags: magento2, xml

I have made a dummy module in Magento2 , just wanted to observer cart add event, but while making few files i am getting this error

```
    a:4:{i:0;s:168:"Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): attributes construct error in Entity, line: 2 in C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Config\Dom.php on line 355";i:1;s:7355:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'DOMDocument::lo...', 'C:\\wamp\\www\\mag...', 355, Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Config\Dom.php(355): DOMDocument->loadXML('<?xml version="...')
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Config\Dom.php(101): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<?xml version="...')
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem.php(175): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<?xml version="...', Array, NULL, NULL)
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem.php(138): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_createConfigMerger('Magento\\Framewo...', '<?xml version="...')
#5 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem.php(119): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
#6 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config\Reader\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('frontend')
#7 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config.php(82): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config\Reader\Proxy->read('frontend')
#8 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config.php(125): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config->_getRoutes(NULL)
#9 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base.php(274): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config->getModulesByFrontName('cms')
#10 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Array)
#11 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#15 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#16 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\app\code\Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php(89): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#20 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCookieVali...')
#24 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\app\code\Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie.php(78): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 [internal function]: Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#28 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\app\code\Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#31 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#32 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\app\code\Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#35 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#36 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#38 C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#39 {main}";s:3:"url";s:18:"/magento2-develop/";s:11:"script_name";s:27:"/magento2-develop/index.php";}
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace?

Comment: in stack trace there is no reference to custom module i have created,also after flushing out content from var/* still the error persists

Comment: Can you show routes.xml  from you custom module?